# Making camel asynchronous call

Tags: apache-camel

I am trying to make an asynchronous call to a webservice using apache camel API.

If I am making normal call, it is working fine. But when I am trying to make asynchronous call then it is not hitting the API. Can you please help me what is the issue here.

```
@Test
public void testSendAsync() {
    Map<String, Object> headers = new HashMap<>();
    headers.put("content-type", "application/json");
    System.out.println("start = "+headers);
    ProducerTemplate template = context.createProducerTemplate();
    /*template.sendBodyAndHeaders("direct:invokeAPI","{\n" +
            "\"source\":\"PDF\"\n" +
            "}", headers);
            */

    Future fut = template.asyncRequestBodyAndHeaders("direct:invokeAPI","{\n" +
            "\"source\":\"PDF\"\n" +
            "}", headers);

    System.out.println("end = "+headers + " , " + fut.isDone());
}
```

In above code `sendBodyAndHeaders` is working fine, I can see that it is hitting the API successfully.

In the case of asynchronous call `asyncRequestBodyAndHeaders`, it is not hitting the API, I am seeing the `system.out` messages for `start` and `end`. What is the issue here?

Comment: is it possible the async request is creating another thread and the test is stopping completion before that other thread has a chance to complete the API operation? can you try to "wait" or "yield" the thread? multi-threading can sometimes be difficult in tests.....

Comment: Thanks it worked now.

Comment: Ok, I moved my comment to an answer - could you please accept it if you found it useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible the async request is creating another thread and the test is stopping completion before that other thread has a chance to complete the API operation.

Can you try to "wait" or "yield" the thread?

Multi-threading can sometimes be difficult in tests.